# Trade options on index or the ETF that tracks the index

Tags: options, index-fund

What is the criteria one should use before deciding on an underlying to trade options on:
1.Options on SPX (Cash settled, European style)
2.Options on SPY ( Settled in SPY shares, American style)

This happens all the time, so the generic question is...whether to trade options on the index itself or on ETF that tracks the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the ETF diverges from the index, the outcome will essentially be the same. So you should base your decision on the characteristics of the options:

- style: European vs American and cash vs physical, which is somewhat neutral
- size (SPY options notional is around $20k vs $200k for SPX options): using SPY options is probably easier for an individual
- execution cost: SPY options tend to be have tighter spreads than SPX options - right now for example on the 205/2050 puts, SPY is 3.73/3.75 (0.5% bid/ask spread) vs 33.1/34.7 (5% spread)
- the dividends streams are different (once a quarter for SPY, potentially every day for SPX)

All in all, SPY options seem a better fit for an individual.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the concept of notional as used in this context?

Comment: [Notional or Nominal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notional_amount)